# Solr Suggestor is not working for sitecore master index

Tags: solr, content-search

I recently tried solr autosuggest search in my local,

Steps I followed :

1. Added configuration in master in sensoft_master_index\conf\solrconfig.xml
   [image]
2. Restarted solr8.1 service in services
3. in C# code,

public IEnumerable GetSuggestion(string term)
        {

```
        try
        {
            using (var context = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("sitecore_master_index").CreateSearchContext())
            {
                SolrSuggestQuery query = term;
                var options = new SuggestHandlerQueryOptions
                {
                    Parameters = new SuggestParameters
                    {
                        Count = 3
                    }
                };

                var result = context.Suggest(query, options);

                return result.Suggestions["default"].Suggestions.Select(a => a.Term);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"D:\test1.txt", e.ToString());
        }
        return rr;
    }
```

But I get the below error

> SolrNet.Exceptions.SolrConnectionException:
>
> 500   36     java.lang.NullPointerException   at
>   org.apache.lucene.search.suggest.fst.FSTCompletionLookup.lookup(FSTCompletionLookup.java:273)
>     at org.apache.lucene.search.suggest.Lookup.lookup(Lookup.java:240)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.SolrSuggester.getSuggestions(SolrSuggester.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.component.SuggestComponent.process(SuggestComponent.java:264)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:298)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:199)
>     at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2566)    at
>   org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.execute(HttpSolrCall.java:756)
>     at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:542)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:397)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:343)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1602)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:540)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1588)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1345)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:480)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1557)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1247)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:220)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:126)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:335)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:502)  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:364)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$DecryptedEndPoint.onFillable(SslConnection.java:411)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection.onFillable(SslConnection.java:305)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$2.succeeded(SslConnection.java:159)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:765)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:683)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)    500    --->
>   System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500)
>   Internal Server Error.    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
>   at HttpWebAdapters.Adapters.HttpWebRequestAdapter.GetResponse()    at
>   SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.GetResponse(IHttpWebRequest request)    at
>   SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.Get(String relativeUrl, IEnumerable`1
>   parameters)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.Get(String relativeUrl, IEnumerable`1
>   parameters)    at
>   Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrNetExtension.Impl.SolrQueryExecuterEx`1.Execute(SolrSuggestQuery
>   query, SuggestHandlerQueryOptions options)    at
>   Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrNetIntegration.SolrNetProxy.Suggest(IProviderSearchContext
>   context, SolrSuggestQuery q, SuggestHandlerQueryOptions options)    at
>   SenSoftPOC.Controllers.HomeController.GetSuggestion(String term) in
>   D:\AmeexProjects\Sensoft\SenSoftPOC\SenSoftPOC\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line
>   197

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- First of all try to remove **dictionaryImpl** parameter.
- Second, from my practice, suggester works only with **AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory** (or without any **lookupImpl**).
- Third, check whether your *fieldtype* that you use for suggester has `stored="true"` in managed schema.

This is an exmaple of working configuration:

```
 <searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
    <lst name="suggester">
      <str name="name">mySuggester</str>
      <str name="lookupImpl">AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory</str>
      <str name="field">pagecontent_t</str>
      <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">text_general</str>
      <str name="buildOnStartup">true</str>
    </lst>
  </searchComponent>
```

Also you can faced issue that you *field* is unknown and it can be resolved by adding your field in suggester defaults in `solrconfig.xml`:

```
  <initParams path="/suggest">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="df">pagebody_t</str>
    </lst>
  </initParams>
```

Comment: <lst name="error">
  <lst name="metadata">
    <str name="error-class">org.apache.solr.common.SolrException</str>
    <str name="root-error-class">org.apache.solr.common.SolrException</str>
  </lst>
  <str name="msg">No suggester named default was configured</str>
  <int name="code">400</int>
</lst>
</response>
 ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

Comment: I tried your suggestions

Comment: Now working. I have a problem with field type. now working

Comment: According to your exception, did you add your custom field in initoram in solrconfig.xml?

Comment: I used default field _name.

Comment: just add your field in solrconfig.xml in /suggest defaults, as I described in my answer

Comment: Thanks I added.  now i want to filter the suggestions base on the path.

Comment: see my question here
https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/24882/how-to-filter-solr-suggestions-only-from-particular-path