# Solr auto suggest from multiple fields

Tags: solr, sitecore-client, sitecore-api

I am trying to `Solr auto suggest` query from multiple fields (say for example, `name_t`, `description_t`) in a single request handler or same `suggest.dictionary`.

I have the configs as below, when I have multiple "**field**" under the same suggester, it's not working. Also, when I try with the same name that's also not working.

```
<searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
<lst name="suggester">
<str name="name">NameSuggester</str>
<str name="lookupImpl">FSTLookupFactory</str>
<str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
<str name="field">name_t</str>    
<str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">string</str>
</lst>  
<lst name="suggester">
<str name="name">DescriptionSuggester</str>
<str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
<str name="lookupImpl">FSTLookupFactory</str>   
<str name="field">description_t</str>            
<str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">string</str>
</lst>  
</searchComponent>

 <requestHandler name="/suggest" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
 <lst name="defaults">
 <str name="suggest">true</str>
 <str name="suggest.count">10</str>
 <str name="suggest.dictionary">DescriptionSuggester</str>
 </lst>
 <arr name="components">
 <str>suggest</str>
 </arr>
 </requestHandler>
```

**C# Code**

```
 using (var ctx = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("sitecore_master_index").CreateSearchContext())
        {
            SolrSuggestQuery q = "Description";
            var options = new SuggestHandlerQueryOptions
            {
                Parameters = new SuggestParameters
                {
                    Count = 10,
                    Build = true
                }
            };

            var result = ctx.Suggest(q, options);
            var resultnew = result.Suggestions["DescriptionSuggester"].Suggestions.Select(a => a.Term);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like related to configuration only. You can try changing your configuration a bit like use `AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory` in `lookupImpl` and also removes `dictionaryImpl`.

```
<searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
     <lst name="suggester">
       <str name="name">mySuggester</str>
       <str name="lookupImpl">AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory</str>
       <str name="field">autocomplete__txtsug</str>
       <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">string</str>
       <str name="buildOnStartup">true</str>
     </lst>
</searchComponent>
```

Also, Add the new field in Managed-Schema file.

```
<fieldType class="solr.TextField" name="textSuggest" positionIncrementGap="100">
   <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
   </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Refer to this for step-by-step details: [Enabling the Suggester from SOLR for the Search box](https://sitecorediaries.org/2021/08/30/enabling-the-suggester-from-solr-for-the-search-box/)

**Updated**

Use `copyfields` to combine multiple fields into a single field and use that field as a suggester.

schema:

```
<copyField source="name" dest="mynewfield" />
<copyField source="other_name" dest="mynewfield" />
```

suggester:

```
<str name="field">mynewfield</str>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I followed the example from the link. schema is like    <copyField source="name_t" dest="autocomplete__txtsug"/> <copyField source="description_t" dest="autocomplete__txtsug"/> This is not copying the values from both fields (name_t, description_t).

Comment: Can you try this one - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7712606/solr-suggester-multiple-field-autocomplete

Comment: Refer this for more details - Copyfield - https://solr.apache.org/guide/6_6/copying-fields.html

Comment: I am able to copy multiple source field to one target field. I can point the copy field to solr.searchcomponent. I am keeping the lookupImpl as "FSTLookupFactory" and dictionaryImpl as "DocumentDictionaryFactory". when i pass a text as query, it matches the prefix or first word from the field. when i pass the 2nd or other than the first word, it's not matching and bringing the suggestion. It looks like, it's more of lookupImpl/dictionaryImpl. For some reason, when i remove the dictionaryImpl, it's not yielding any results. may be the correct combination of these 2 is important. Do you have?

Comment: I've used `AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory` it works fine without any issues. It also supports `Context filtering`. Context filtering lets you filter suggestions by a separate context field, such as category, department, or any other token.  Refer to this for more details https://solr.apache.org/guide/6_6/suggester.html

Comment: I am also reading that this "AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory" will do the trick to suggest from the field middle of the text also. But i am not sure why this is not working. This lookup impl also searching the start or prefix of the field only.

Comment: Let's see if it trick works or not. try those bulleted points or validate them - https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/24875/solr-suggestor-is-not-working-for-sitecore-master-index

Comment: This works Sumit. Thanks. Issue is i had suggestAnalyzerFieldType wrong.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that, If this answer or any other one solved your issue or helps to resolve it, please mark it as accepted for the community. For more details https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Adding one more thing with the configuration you have already done with. You can try rebuilding your suggested like below.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/index_name/suggest?suggest.build=true
```

Until you do this step, no suggestions are returned.

After completing this ask for suggestions like below.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/index_name/suggest?suggest.q=whatever
```

The response will contain a **suggest** field. This field will contain fields for each of the `suggest.dictionaries` that was used. Each of these dictionary fields will have a "**numFound**" field as well as a "**suggestions**" field containing an array of the found suggestions.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Hi Sumit, Thanks, i was facing a config issue to copy more than one source field to one destination field. This works now. But the suggestion is suggesting based on the first or prefix of the value from the particular configured field. when i pass any word other than the first, it's not yielding any result.